# AWS Lambda cannot reach internal servers from within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpn, vpc

I have a lambda which is attempting to make a REST call to an on-prem server outside of AWS.  We have the lambda running from a VPC which has a VPN connection to our local resources.  The same rest call runs successfully from EC2 with the VPC but the lambda request hangs.  The security groups are open.   Any ideas how to debug this?

Here is the bulk of the lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config')

    pattern = re.compile(".*"+config['DEFAULT']['my-pattern'])
    logger.info(event['Records'])
    sns_json = event['Records'][0]['Sns']
    sns_message = json.loads(sns_json['Message'])
    logger.info(sns_message['Records'][0]['s3'])
    s3_object = sns_message['Records'][0]['s3']
    new_file_name = s3_object['object']['key']
    bucket = s3_object['bucket']['name']
    if pattern.match(new_file_name):
        new_json = {"text": "New file (" + new_file_name + ") added to the bucket. " + bucket,
                   "title": config['DEFAULT']['default_message_title']}
        webhook_post = requests.get("http://some-ip:4500/")
        logger.info("Webhook Post Status: " + str(webhook_post.status_code) + str(webhook_post))
        logger.info("Skip teams webhook");
        outgoing_message_dict = {
            's3Bucket': bucket,
            'somefile': new_file_name
        }
        return outgoing_message_dict
```

I don't receive any errors from the request, it just hangs until my lambda times-out.

Comment: what happens when your lambda is outside the VPC? And is your lambda in private subnet or public subnet?

Comment: Is the Lambda function connected to the same Subnets as the EC2 instance that you say works? Is `some-ip` a Public IP address or a private IP address (eg `10.`)? Is the EC2 instance that works in a public or private subnet?

Comment: @john The Lambda is running on the same subnets as the EC2 which are private.

Comment: @deosha The Lambda works well outside the VPC but of course I cannpt reach my internal resources.

Comment: Which IP you have opened in your own prem firewalls? For EC2 it will work because you can open private IP on your own prem firewalls. Lambda has no static IP

Comment: @deosha I think this is a good point.  But I believe we opened up all IPs in the range of the CIDR of the VPC (i did not configure it).  I don't have to send out network admin my IP to get EC2 to work.  I just start and instance and it works.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a chance this our VPN connection is not being kept alive from our local network.  I received a different error when I made sure the VPN was active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the source of the problem.  Ultimately I believe the issue is with our on-prem firewall.  The VPN tunnel wasn't active at all times.  Others have mentioned that it needs to be activated from the on-prem network.  I created an ec2 instance and connected to it, activating the VPN.  What I ran the lambda shortly after, I could successfully reach the local REST endpoint I was trying connect to.

I have not implemented the final solution yet, but from the firewall we should be able to set the connection to have a keep-alive ping so our connection does not time-out.  I hope this helps others.  Thank you for the feedback!